# Finding the inverse laplace $\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{\frac{1}{-s^2-2s+37}\}=?$

Tags: laplace-transform

How to find the inverse laplace. I have really no idea. I would appreciate if anybody helps
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{\frac{1}{-s^2-2s+37}\}=?$$

Comment: $$L^{-1}\dfrac{-1}{(s+1)^2-\sqrt{38}^2}=\dfrac{-e^{-t}}{\sqrt{38}}\sinh\sqrt{38}t$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, consider the Laplace transform of the following function:

$$\text{F}\left(\text{s}\right):=\mathscr{L}_t\left[\frac{2}{\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}\cdot e^{-\frac{\text{b}t}{2\text{a}}}\cdot\sinh\left(t\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}{2\text{a}}\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\tag1$$

We can set the 'constant' in front:

$$\text{F}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}\cdot\mathscr{L}_t\left[e^{-\frac{\text{b}t}{2\text{a}}}\cdot\sinh\left(t\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}{2\text{a}}\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\tag2$$

Using the '[frequency shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems)' property of the Laplace transform, we get:

$$\text{F}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}\cdot\mathscr{L}_t\left[\sinh\left(t\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}{2\text{a}}\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}+\frac{\text{b}}{2\text{a}}\right)}\tag3$$

Now, using the Laplace transform of the [hyperbolic sine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms), we get:

$$\text{F}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}\cdot\frac{\frac{\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}{2\text{a}}}{\left(\text{s}+\frac{\text{b}}{2\text{a}}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}{2\text{a}}\right)^2}\tag4$$

When $\Re\left(\text{s}+\frac{\text{b}}{2\text{a}}\right)>\left|\frac{\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}{2\text{a}}\right|$

And $\left(4\right)$, simplifies to:

$$\text{F}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{1}{\text{a}\cdot\text{s}^2+\text{b}\cdot\text{s}+\text{c}}\tag5$$

---

> So, when $\text{a}=-1,\text{b}=-2,\text{c}=37$:
>
> $$\text{f}\left(t\right)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{38}}\cdot\exp\left(-t\right)\cdot\sinh\left(\sqrt{38}\cdot t\right)\tag6$$